# reducing the query string length

Tags: java, url-rewriting

In my web application, we encrypt the query parameters using `PBEWithMD5AndDES` and then encode it using `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode()`. It makes the length of whole URL more than 140 characters. Is there a way without changing encryption & encoding , I can reduce the length to around 80 characters? If I have to change the encryption algorithm and encoding to reduce the length, what should I be using keeping security in mind?

Comment: I guess one will be able to help you better if you let us know which encryption algorithm you are using.

Comment: You could count output length after base64 encoding like new length nearly equal to old length * 1.33. To reduce output length you should try algos with bigger alphabet (like base85).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base64 encoding has its known overhead, and encryption also has an overhead - switching to a different encoding algorithm may reduce the overhead and so might the encryption algorithm - but I see no sure bets here - you might reduce it to be 139 characters for your current data set, but any additional data requirements might again repeat the problem.

I see two options:

1. Compress the data before you encrypt it -
    **Pros**: Relatively easy to develop.
    **Cons**: May effect performance, might not reduce the size sufficiently.
2. Use POST and pass the parameter in the response body instead of as a query parameter.
   **Pros**: Encrypted data is not logged on server logs (security), size is "unlimited"
   **Cons**: Might require significantly more development time, might not be possible in your environment altogether (external requirements, technology issues etc.)

I would go for option #2 given the chance.

Comment: Thanks. Option 2 is not something I can go at the moment. I will try the first one if I can do it quickly. How do I compress the query parameters?

Comment: Check out this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5934620/357360
Also - here is another example which is more Strings related: http://www.coderanch.com/t/374637/java/java/Compressing-Decompressing-strings-Java

Comment: Thanks, I tried those things, but sometimes it reduces the length and sometimes it increases the length. Very fluctuating.

Comment: So sending the value in the response/request body via POST is your only resort.

Comment: Another option would be to split the value into two query parameters-but passing it in the body is much better - what is the reason you are avoiding it?

Comment: The reason I am avoiding it, it will make me rewrite whole application.

Answer (score 1):

Only you can reduce the length of name of query parameter.
If you will try for for any type of encoding it will increase length of query.

So I will suggest use form submission rather then query based submission.
Or please post your complete scenario which will show that in which conditions you want to submit your data.